# Boot issues on Windows 7 enterprise

Tags: windows-7, recovery-disk

I'm running windows 7 enterprise at mcdonalds.

We we're given a  recovery disk to restart our machine with.

Our optic drive then stopped working.

I've tried burning an iso image of the file on to a USB stick and booting from that. However I get as far as a screen that says `boot:`  and will not recognize the iso file.

I then tried copying the entire contents of the disk onto a the USB which included a file called `BOOTMGR` and `autorun`.

When I type `BOOTMGR` it says:

> ```
> Loading BOOTMGR... Ok
> Booting kernal failed: Invalid arguement'
> ```

Comment: How did you burn ISO to USB stick? In case of Windows 7/8 there is an official tool named [Windows 7 USB DVD tool](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool) which works fine (download [here](http://images2.store.microsoft.com/prod/clustera/framework/w7udt/1.0/en-us/Windows7-USB-DVD-tool.exe)).

Comment: I'm using a specific recovery disk issued by mcdonalds to recover their pc's - I have their recovery disk - I had made an .iso before but not used rufus to transfer it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a bootable USB stick, currently your PC doesn't know it can boot from the USB stick as there is no boot sector.

There are many free programs for doing this, Rufus is one (http://rufus.akeo.ie/), you can also use DISKPART in windows cmd (http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-USB-Bootable)